# Design a class that returns multiple interfaces in a unified way

Tags: c++, com

I have a C++ class, that may optionally support some additional functionality (defined by abstract interfaces). 
In Microsoft COM there is a way to ask a class for such functionality by using `QueryInterface(GUID, void**)`. This requires to reinterpret_cast all interfaces to void*. My question is - is there a safer way to achieve the same without using cast?

Comment: Within a single module or across module boundaries?  (And, how modular do your modules need to be?)

Comment: within single module is fine. Hmm, "how modular" - what do you mean?

Comment: Remember to accept an answer when you find it useful.

Comment: One of the benefits of the COM QI model is that it allows for arbitrary extensibility:  a component can add functionality at any time without breaking existing clients.  If you are only using the component within a single module, or if your module is unlikely to require this ability to add additional functionality, then some of those benefits don't matter.  Mark's answer is a reasonable approach if you want to allow a more limited sort of extensibility; another alternative would be to implement the interfaces then `dynamic_cast` to them; this will work if everything is in a single module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM has the requirement of obtaining any interface from any other supported by an object. You don't have to live by that requirement. Just add getters to every interface you would expect to support.

```
struct IBase
{
    IMoreCapabilities * GetMoreCapabilities();
};
```